# mysql subquery issue on comments voting 

Tags: mysql, join, count, subquery

I have MySQL query which I think needs a subquery. I'd like to count the total number of "up" votes on each of many comments and determine whether a given user has already voted on each comment:

Here are my tables:

```
Comments Table:
  comment_id  comment      acct_id     topic_id    comment_date
      5        hello5        2             1            9:00am
      7        hello7        3             1           10:00am

  Votes Table:
  comment_id   vote        acct_id     topic_id
     5          1             1            1
     7          1             4            1
     5          1             5            1
```

here's the output i'm getting:

```
  comment_id  commenter  comment  voter   sum    did_i_vote 
      5           2      hello5     1      2          1 
      7           3      hello7     4      1          1
```

Here's the desired output:

```
  comment_id  commenter  comment  voter   sum    did_i_vote 
      5           2      hello5   **5**    2          1 
      7           3      hello7     4      1          1
```

Here's my query:

```
SELECT votes.acct_id as voter, comments.comment_id, comment, comments.acct_id as 
commenter, SUM(vote) as sum, vote as did_i_vote
from votes 
right join comments 
on votes.comment_id=comments.comment_id 
join accounts on comments.acct_id=accounts.acct_id 
where topic_id=1 
group by comments.comment_id order by comment_date desc
```

You'll notice these 2 outputs are identical except for `voter`.

What my query is missing is a way to determine whether a given user, for example with `voter=acct_id=5`, was the one who voted on any of the comments. Without that condition, the query picks the first `voter` in the list which for `comment_id=5` is `voter=1`.

So my question is I think I need to insert the following subquery:

```
SELECT from votes where voter='X'
```

I'm just not sure where or how. Putting it in parentheses in between the `from` and `votes` above eliminates the `sum()` function so I'm stuck.

Any thoughts?

Comment: But if, as in your example, a comment has received votes from multiple users... which voter should appear in your output?

Comment: hi eggyal, I'd like the query to not only select all comments and their total votes but also to select whether  acct_id=X has voted on the comment.

Comment: Is that not what the `did_i_vote` column does?  Which voter should appear in the `voter` column?

Comment: yes, that's what the did_i_vote column is **supposed** to do. Whether voter="X"  voted should appear in that column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly from your comments above, I think all you need to do is (outer) join the `votes` table to your query another time, this time only on the votes of the account in question:

```
SELECT
   comments.comment_id       AS comment_id,
   comments.acct_id          AS commenter,
   comment                   AS comment,
-- votes.acct_id             AS voter,                        -- ambiguous
   SUM(votes.vote)           AS sum,
   my_votes.vote IS NOT NULL AS did_i_vote
FROM
             votes
  RIGHT JOIN comments ON votes.comment_id=comments.comment_id
        JOIN accounts ON comments.acct_id=accounts.acct_id    -- what purpose ?
  LEFT  JOIN votes AS my_votes ON
               my_votes.commentid=comments.comment_id
           AND my_votes.acct_id=@my_acct_id
WHERE topic_id = 1                                            -- ambiguous
GROUP BY comments.comment_id
ORDER BY comment_date DESC
```

Comment: hi eggyal, awesome! that works exactly as I needed. can you explain the difference in outer join vs. subquery? I guess I'm still not sure when to use one vs. the other.

Comment: @timpeterson: An outer join connects two tables together, but if even there are no matches on the join condition it won't eliminate any records from the `LEFT` or `RIGHT` table (as specified): those records still appear but with `NULL` in every column of the table on the other side of the join.  A subquery is any use of another `SELECT` query within your query - it need not be joined to your other tables, but if it is then like any other join it could be inner or outer; you can use subqueries in your `WHERE` clause, for example, and not join them with the tables in your query.  Does that help?